# SQL: How to replace an entire field if it matches a string?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, oracle, replace

I am trying to replace an entire field from a database when it matches a certain string.

For example:
TABLE_FRUITS contains

```
ID     NAME
---------------
1      APPLE
2      ORANGE
3      PASSIONFRUIT
4      BANANA
5      DRAGONFRUIT
6      KIWI
7      STRAWBERRY FRUIT
```

Now If I try to select column NAME, and if a field contains the string 'FRUIT', it should replace that whole field to another string, like 'SAMPLE'.

Expected result:

```
select NAME from TABLE_FRUITS;
```

would return:

```
APPLE
ORANGE
SAMPLE
BANANA
SAMPLE
KIWI
SAMPLE
```

I am not sure if I should use replace or substr/instr.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MySQL, you could use something like

```
SELECT IF(NAME LIKE '%FRUIT%', 'SAMPLE', NAME) AS NAME FROM TABLE_FRUIT
```

In other varieties of SQL you will probably need to use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN NAME LIKE '%FRUIT%' THEN 'SAMPLE' ELSE NAME END AS NAME FROM TABLE_FRUIT
```

Comment: Which dbms is this for?

Comment: @jarlh Question is tagged MySQL, but I see it is also tagged Oracle so have updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use case when:

```
select case when name like '%fruit%' then 'Sample' else name end from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE`

```
select case when name like '%FRUIT%' then 'sample' else name end 
from table_fruit
```